# Word Press & Elementor: Customize Spacer size for different screen Width

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I was wondering if anyone has attempted to create responsive spacers and come across the following issue.

I am trying to customize a specific spacer in my home page such that below a certain screen size (i.e width), the size of that particular spacer will be zero pixels. I am using word press and Elementor pro.

What i have tried to do is select the spacer, right click then edit spacer --> advanced --> custom css ... and i have inserted the following code however nothing seems to happen:

```
/* Remove spacer block */
@media screen and (max-width:740px) {
.spacer-block {
    display: none !important;
}
}
```

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Many thanks,
MJ

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use margins instead of the spacer. For example:

```
@media screen and (min-width:741px) {
.my-element {
margin-top: 50px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:740px) {
.my-element {
margin-top: 0px;
}
}
```